# No such file directory exists?

Tags: directory, connection, root, document-root

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I am using this .inc file to link my php page to MySQL however my browsers says the following message as :

```
 Warning: require_once(../FinalApplicationDWP/Public_html/dbstuff.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cs12jkk/public_html/functions.inc on line 6
```

and

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../FinalApplicationDWP/Public_html/dbstuff.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/cs12jkk/public_html/functions.inc on line 6
```

My filies are saved on in a file on my desktop FinalApplicationDWP>public_html> then all the files

```
<?php

require_once ("..dbstuff.inc");
require_once ("validation.inc");

?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not finding the file in the require_once lines.

For starters try:

```
require_once ("../dbstuff.inc");
```

Notice the extra /

Other than that check the file paths, make sure they are in the correct place.

Comment: just tried that and still getting the same error message, thanks for trying though :)

Comment: try a fully qualified path as opposed to a relative one

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code to::

```
<?php

require_once("file:///jordanking48$/Users/jordanking48/Desktop/FinalApplicationDWP/public_html/dbstuff.inc");
require_once ("validation.inc");

?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and make sure that you gice the right path for the files changing `<"..dbstuff.inc">` to `<"../dbstuff.inc">`

Comment: how do I check/ change the paths? I've changed to code and still getting the same error message in the web browser.

Comment: Do 1 thing,to check just give the full path as             file:///c:/user/................/FinalApplicationDWP/Public_html/dbstuff.inc and check if it is picking up

Comment: do I just copy the code you have just given? And where do I place it to check?

Comment: @user3192530  ok just give me your full path of your file location ,like:: c:/user.......

Comment: put the full file location as file:///c:/user.............../FinalApplicationDWP/Public_html/dbstuff.inc   in require_once("//HERE")

Comment: jordanking48$ /Users/jordanking48/Desktop/FinalApplicationDWP/public_html/dbstuff.inc

Comment: i'm still getting this message: Warning: require_once(file:///jordanking48$/Users/jordanking48/Desktop/FinalApplicationDWP/public_html/dbstuff.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cs12jkk/public_html/functions.inc on line 6

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'file:///jordanking48$/Users/jordanking48/Desktop/FinalApplicationDWP/public_html/dbstuff.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/cs12jkk/public_html/functions.inc on line 6

Comment: this is the page that requires the destuff.inc file if that helps: <?php require_once("functions.inc"); ?> then that is the functions.inc page above